# Shallow copy - LINQ - how to sum values from list of list of list - from database - entity

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

i have a problem.

Belowe are my examples entity models.

```
{
class Garage{
    long height;
    IEnumerable<Car> cars;
}

class Car{
    IEnumerable<Wheel> wheels;
}

class Wheel{
    IEnumerable<Tire> tires;
    IEnumerable<Rim> rims;
}

class Tire{
    decimal value;
    float width;
}

class Rim{
    decimal value;
    float weight;
}
```

In databese I have a garage of id = 1 with five cars , and garage of id = 2 with 3 cars.

1. I would like to sum value of cars tires from this garages.(each wheel has a different value)
2. I would like to sum value of cars rims from this garages.(each rim has a different value)

How to do this using LinQ?

I tried to use something like this, but it's not work.

```
var allTiresValue = context.Garage.Sum(garage => garage.cars
                                  .Sum(car => car.wheels
                                  .Sum(wheel => wheel.tires
                                  .Sum(tire => tire.value))));
```

It's probably not workin becouse linq creating "shallow copy", but i don't have any idea how to make it's works :/

Comment: What do you want exactly. The sum per garage or for all in one result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm going to suppose that is not your real EF model because your columns and relationships weren't represented using properties, but I'm going to suppose you have those navigation properties.

If you want to find the `Rims` value and the `Tires` value of all the cars that belong to an specific `Garage`, you can do something like this:

```
var garageId=1;
var query=from car in context.Cars
          where car.GarageId==garageId
          select new {
                        CarTiresValue= car.Wheels.SelectMany(w=>w.Tires).Sum(t=>t.Value),
                        CarRimsValue=car.Wheels.SelectMany(w=>w.Rims).Sum(r=>r.Value)
                     };
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your example you want the sum of all values of all tires of all wheels of all cars in all garages.

If you had one sequence of all tires, then you would only have to sum their values.

In linq, whenever you see a sequence of sequences, and you want one sequence, then you use SelectMany.

For example, a school has a sequence of classes and each class has a sequence of pupils. To get one sequence of all pupils in the school:

```
var allPupiles = School.SelectMany(class => class.Pupils).
```

In your example: to get the total values of all wheels of all cars in all garages:

```
var allGarages = context.Garage;
var allCars = allGarages.SelectMany(garage => garage.Cars);
var allWheels = allCars.SelectMany(car => car.Wheels);
var totalValue = allWheels.Sum(wheel => wheel.Value);
```

Now all you have to do is put this into one statement.